# How can I change http to https in django rest browsable api when I am using apache2 + gunicorn

Tags: django, apache, docker, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

The set up is

- Apache2 as a reverse proxy
- gunicorn serves django rest app
- gunicorn + django app + mysql are in docker

Now the problem is in the browsable API, gunicorn serves the app at `http://0.0.0.0:8000` but I use `https://example.com/` as in Apache config. Every link in the browsable API is in the form of `http://xxxxx`.

When clicks the link, it redirects to http protocol, resulting in 404.

How can I tell gunicorn or django app to use https in the browsable API?

Edit:

gunicorn command: `gunicorn -w 3 waxis_topup_api_django.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload`

setting.py is just an ordinary one without anything specific to http/https

apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin xxx
ServerName example.com
Alias "/static" "/path/static"
ProxyPass "/static/" !
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8000/"
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

### Current workaround(solution?)

I can only think of this to force any http to be https, so even if there is a HTTP link in browsable API, it will be redirected to https by apache. I don't know if this is correct but it is more like a hack to me.

Here is my config in apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you share your `settings.py`, gunicorn and apache configurations please?

Comment: @GokhanSari Hi, I've added the configs, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, one of the middleware web servers (apache or ngninx, or both) is not forwarding host, so Django is confused about the hostname it is serving on.

For apache, you need:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

and for nginx you need:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

These will make apache and nginx forward the hostname and django will use it.

Comment: Hey man, it is the protocol! not hostname, this problem did occur but a google search helped me to fix it. However, I can't find anything related to my issue.